# download via HTTP_REFERER in .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, video

I have 2 domains, one is allow-site.com and the other is resource.com.

resource.com's file structure is:

```
root
 |--- videos
 |      |---> 01.mp4
 |      |---> 02.avi
 |--- index.php
 |--- .htaccess
 |
```

**index.php** contains a download link like:

```
<a href="http://localhost/resource/videos/01.mp4" download>Download</a>
```

In **.htaccess** I only allow the `allow-site.com` domain via an **HTTP_REFERER** RewriteCond, which allows allow-site.com's video players to play the videos correctly.

The **.htaccess** file is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# allow these referers to passthrough
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://localhost/allow [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# redirect everything else
RewriteRule ^ https://google.com/ [R,L]
```

I don't want anybody to use the video links except if they come from `allow-site.com`, which is the purpose of this **.htaccess** file, and it works fine.

But the main problem is when I click on the download link, it downloads an HTML file not the video. If I ignore `RewriteRule ^ https://google.com/ [R,L]`, it works as expected (the video downloads fine) but the videos can be used by anybody, from any other domain.

I don't understand how to solve the problem.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure about what I'm saying 'cause I don't use apache often but can't you get your htaccess to redirect to google for every referer that IS NOT localhost/allow ? And what about direct linking ? Without referer ?

Comment: I guess the download attribute doesn't send a referrer so your rewrite rules forces the user to download the google homepage. Check what headers are sent buy the download request in Chrome dev tools, you'll be able to see if there's a referrer or not (I guess not)

Comment: i am sorry, it my localhost project

Answer (score 0):

The `download` attribute on links probably strips the referrer by default, hence the user downloading the source of Google's homepage and not the video, because the `RewriteCond` is not met and the `RewriteRule` kicks in.

You could try to force a `referrerpolicy="origin"` on the link and see if it fixes the issue, but it doesn't seem to be well supported at the moment (http://caniuse.com/#feat=referrer-policy)

Also, your rewrite rules can be simplified to:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# allow these referers to passthrough
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://localhost/allow [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://google.com/ [R,L]
```

Comment: i use **referrerpolicy="origin"**. but it redirect to google.com.

Comment: I guess the referrer policy only applies to the normal link but not when it's a download link. What happens if you remove the download attribute? I guess you can play the video OK in a new tab? (doesn't solve the issue but interesting to test to rule that out)

Comment: no it is not playing the video. it redirect to google home page

Comment: Interesting... Do you get the same behaviour in all the browsers you tested that with?

Comment: yes it's same for all (chome, firefox, uc and ms edge)

Comment: I've seen some antiviruses/firewall stripping the referrer from requests, you don't use any, do you?

Comment: ok can you tell me any other alternative concept for my project?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143944/discussion-between-jayanta-and-capsule).